# C# reading console output of a 3rd party tool with a correct code page

Tags: c#, encoding, console

We have to execute a 3rd party sw which is a console tool and writes some text to the output. We sepcify the output encoding before the execution as follow:

```
 var proc = new Process {
  StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = exeName,
    Arguments = cmdLineArgs,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
 },
 EnableRaisingEvents = true,
};
```

We read the output as:

```
var stdOut = new StringBuilder();
proc.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)                    
  => stdOut.Append(e.Data + "\r\n");
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

We constructed a simple console tool to test it:

```
System.Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
System.Console.WriteLine("2 На берегу пустынных волн Τη γλώσσα μου έδωσαν ελληνική Pòsso mangiâ o veddro e o no me fà mâ.");
```

The strange that even if we set the output encoding or not - we cannot read the output back (we found somee ?? ???? ???? string instead).

The real issue is to read a 3rd party tool output in a correct way. We dont know if the tool sets the output encoding or not. When not - what is the encoding it uses. But until we cannot read our own tool output correctly - there is no chance to read the 3rd party as well. What do we miss now? Any advice is welcome!

Comment: I tried to set the console output encoding of the "host" program, the StandardOutputEncoding. I tried to redirect the output to a text file using cmd pipeline. I tried to call the exe from a windows cmd, and before the call use chcp 65001. Nothing helped.

Comment: To correct: when the console tool sets the output encoding to UTF8, all the chars are good. But when he does not do that - nothing will help.